# Я не могу реализовать сообщение при входе и выходе с канала дискорд на пайтон

Tags: python, discord, join

Я не могу реализовать сообщение при входе и выходе с канала дискорд на `python`

```
async def on_member_join(member):
    print("Recognised that a member called " + member.name + " joined")
    try: 
        await client.send_message(member, STARTER_MESSAGE)
        print("Sent message to " + member.name)
    except:
        await client.send_message(member, STARTER_MESSAGE)
        print("Couldn't message " + member.name)
    embed=discord.Embed(
        title="Welcome "+member.name+"!",
        description="We're so glad you're here!",
        color=discord.Color.green()
    )
@client.event
async def on_member_leave(member):
    print("Recognised that a member called " + member.name + " left")
    embed=discord.Embed(
        title=" Goodbye "+member.name+"!",
        description="Until we meet again old friend.",
        color=discord.Color.red())
```

Мне выдает ошибку:
[image: Мне выдает ошибку]

[image: Код ошибки]

Comment: смотри. если у пользователя в настройках стоит фильтр на личные сообщения, то ты ему никак DM не отправишь. Это на будущее. а тебе, чтобы было понятнее, надо наконец сделать толковые блоки except. у тебя ошибка вылетает, а ты предлагаешь нам пованговать?) давай текст ошибки!

Comment: @alex, здравствуйте, я учел свою ошибку и исправил статью, мне нужно не личное сообщение, а что бы в чате выводился текст приветствия

Comment: @IPOleksenko, так ты явно пытаешься отправить в личные сообщения. Я с библиотекой не особо знаком, попробуй вместо `client.send_message(member, STARTER_MESSAGE)` использовать `client.send(STARTER_MESSAGE)`

Answer (score 1):

смотри. у тебя ошибка в том что у объекта client нет метода, который ты хочешь вызвать. это раз. у тебя member это объект пользователя. я предположу что ты для работы с дискордом юзаешь пакет `discord.py`. Тогда для отправки сообщения в канал тебе нужен будет ID чата в гильдии куда ты зашлешь сообщение.

```
DISCORD_LOG_CHANNEL_ID: int

async def on_member_join(member):
    print("Recognised that a member called " + member.name + " joined")
    try: 
        logs_channel = client.get_channel(DISCORD_LOG_CHANNEL_ID)
        await logs_channel.send("Recognised that a member called " + member.name + " joined")
        print("Sent message to " + member.name)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"{type(e).__name__}{getattr(e, 'args', None)}")
        print("Couldn't message " + member.name)
    embed=discord.Embed(
        title="Welcome "+member.name+"!",
        description="We're so glad you're here!",
        color=discord.Color.green()
    )
```

DISCORD_LOG_CHANNEL_ID - должен быть идшником чата.